# Fading images in, with the current basic JQuery Image gallery i have used

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // swaps the images on hover
    $("#imgGallery li img").hover(function(){
        $('#main').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumbnail/', ''));
    });
    // Image pre-load
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#imgGallery li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumbnail/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgGallery">
  <img src="gallery/img1.jpg" alt="" id="main" />
  <ul>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/thumbnail/img7.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Above is the code that i have used to make a very basic thumbnail image gallery, could you have a quick look and show me how to fade the images in.

Comment: check jQuery api. `fadeIn` & `fadeOut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, jQuery has [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

But it looks like you want to fade from one image to another, which is a different type of fading called 'crossfade'. In a crossfade scenario, one image fades out and the other fades in.

Checkout this link for a jQuery crossfade implementation: 
http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/